# How can I correctly type `let skills` using this generated typescript code?

Tags: typescript

I'm using typescript to describe a variable but I'm encountering a strange issue:

```
import type { PlayerByIdQuery } from "generated/queries";

let skills: PlayerByIdQuery["playerById"]["skills"];
```

The error is:

```
Property 'skills' does not exist on type '{ __typename?: "Player" | undefined; id: string; number: string; skills?: { ...; }[] | ... 1 more ....'.ts(2339)
```

The type is:

```
export type PlayerByIdQuery = {
  __typename?: "Query";
  playerById?: {
    __typename?: "Player";
    id: string;
    number: string;
    skills?: Array<{
      __typename?: "PlayerSkill";
      description: string;
      id: string;
      playerId: string;
    }> | null;
  } | null;
};
```

It works if I change the type to (note the both missing  `| null`):

```
export type PlayerByIdQuery = {
  __typename?: "Query";
  playerById: {
    __typename?: "Player";
    id: string;
    number: string;
    skills?: Array<{
      __typename?: "PlayerSkill";
      description: string;
      id: string;
      playerId: string;
    }>;
  };
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

How can I correctly type `let skills`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `playerById` is optional (may be `undefined`) or `null`.

And `null['skills']` is not valid, which means that:

```
type A = { skills: string[] } | null
type B = A['skills'] // also not valid
```

So you need to explicitly remove the `undefined` and `null` from the type before you drill into it.

Luckily, typescript comes with a utility type for just that called `NonNullable<T>`.

```
type A = { skills: string[] } | null
type B = NonNullable<A>['skills'] // now works fine
```

So now just apply this to your own types like so:

```
let skills: NonNullable<PlayerByIdQuery["playerById"]>["skills"] = [
  {
    __typename: 'PlayerSkill',
    description: 'Fancy punch',
    id: 'abc123',
    playerId: 'def456'
  }
]
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKAbAho4UBCiAkgCYCKArnonALxwDeAUHHAPptIoB2WAtsAD8ALjgAiStTEBuFnDDZcBYiRGM5rDl2C8BasZhx4ZGuAEsSogM4woZ7gHNZrVtwp8ARnmu37T01YA1mYYGFZqAIJQUDgAPMwuLlrIOvxCogaKeADKwaEmiawkwFYAxnZgMGYQ3D52js6FFnV+jYkKRlCkLQ2mAL4AfHAAPnBuoY19I2MUE0x9skxMGMDwQSFhogByNVuz2B4rsYZKhKSSUIgA2mIdpypiALoDN+uhVk90cFdyCUmcKV0wFEAHITjk8hgQQAaUzFMoVKo1UEAMSw3FKNDAFAxAAsYaZmnAQVgPKUAIwAJgAzAT2lkupZicUAGYAFgArAA2EFyPpMR5AA)